# get EntityKey in codeFirst

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

We recently introduced `CodeFirst` in our project and we want to get rid of the `EDMX` file. So when adjusting the code for the `CodeFirst`, how can I get the `EntityKey` of an entity object? Ex: before we had: `myEntity.EntityKey`, but now, the entity from CodeFirst  does not contain a definition for `EntityKey`. How to achieve this, so we make as few as possible changes to the code?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.CreateEntityKey("key_name", myEntity)
```

From MSDN: Creates the entity key for a specific object, or returns the entity key if it already exists

In my case, it will return the existent `EntityKey`